# Questions page not opening

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am getting an error message when I try to ask a question. I am a beginner and I don't know much about web configuration. please tell me how to find and change the web.config file. They have given in detail how to do but I could not get it.

Here's the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error Description: An
>   application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web> </configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's 
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on Stack Overflow or one of the Stack Exchange sites?  Or are you asking about some application you've developed?  I highly doubt you're seeing it on a Stack site, but I gotta ask.

Comment: No.I could not ask questions in stackoverflow forum.Its showing me a runtime error as the above.

Answer (score 1):

This was an error on [our (read: my) part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94261/has-the-search-page-moved-or-is-it-simply-broken/94264#94264).

The response code has been rolled back, question submission should be consistently working again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me.So i dont want to do any modification from my side.I can wait for few hours to ask questions isnt it.

Comment: its working now.i could able to post questions now.