# Has the search page moved, or is it simply broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

https://stackoverflow.com/search is referenced in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and various posts, but appears to be broken. In Chrome, I see the url changed to `https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/search` and a page of error messages starting with:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Answer (score 1):

This one was my bad, a change to our view lookup code kind of sort of broke... a lot of things.

Its been rolled back.